# Django: Is it possible to limit ContentType by base Parent?

Tags: django, django-models, orm, relational-database

I have an Abstract base class "Parent" from which derive two subclasses "Child1" and "Child2". Each child can have a set of "Status".
I used "ContentType", "GenericForeignKey" and "GenericRelation" like so:

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.contenttypes.generic import GenericRelation, GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Child1(Parent):
    id_camp = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    config_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    status_set = GenericRelation(Status)


class Child2(Parent):
    temperature = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    status_set = GenericRelation(Status)


class Status(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to={'name__in': ('child1', 'child2',)}, null=True, blank=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

The actual solution works fine, but right now the limitation of choices of content type is by "name" and eventually I will create more subclacess of Parent later. I would like to replace `limit_choices_to={'name__in': ('child1', 'child2',)}` with somthing like `limit_choices_to children of parent` is there any straightforward way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) also accepts callables, so yes, a dynamic value should be possible:

> Either a dictionary, a Q object, or a callable returning a dictionary or Q object can be used.

So something along these lines should work:

```
def get_children():
   return {'model__in': [c.__name__ for c in Parent.__subclasses__()]}
```

and then later ...

```
limit_choices_to=get_children
```

Or even in one line:

```
limit_choices_to={'model__in': [c.__name__ for c in Parent.__subclasses__()]}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer was helphul, I modified it and used it, I converted the list to tuple (not necessary) and replaced "name__in" with "model__in" .